# Join two 2 tables to get sum of each year - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables below. **Common column is ObjectId.**

**Table 1**:

```
    Year  ObjectId G_Amount
   =====  ======== ========-
    2010  1234       5.00
    2010  1234       5.00
    2010  5678      10.00
    2010  5678      20.00
    2010  5678      50.00
    2012  9101       0.00
    2012  1122      70.00
    2012  1122     100.00
```

**Table 2**:

```
    ObjectId   I_Amount
   =========  ===========-
    1234       10.00
    1234       30.00
    5678       15.00
    5678       20.00
    9101       25.00
    9101       35.00
    1122       10.00
    1122        0.00
```

I want to join above 2 table such that the resultset becomes like below. `G_Amount` (total of `g_amount` for each year from Table 1) & `I_Amount` (total of `i_amount` for each year from Table 2) should be displayed year wise.

Result set:

```
    Year  G_Amount  I_Amount
    ===== ========  ========-
    2010   90.00     75.00
    2012  170.00     70.00
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY and SUM().

Comment: `SUM() ..GROUP BY`

Comment: How do I merge two tables, I can do Groupby and sum on each table. ?

Comment: Use JOIN to combine two tables into one result table dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work for your dataset. I've included a `LEFT JOIN` for any values in `Table1` that aren't in `Table2`:

```
SELECT
    T1.[Year]
    , SUM(T1.G_Amount_Total) G_Amount
    , ISNULL(SUM(T2.I_Amount_Total), 0) I_Amount
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [Year]
            , ObjectId
            , SUM(G_Amount) G_Amount_Total
        FROM Table1
        GROUP BY
            [Year]
            , ObjectId
    ) T1
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                ObjectId
                , SUM(I_Amount) I_Amount_Total
            FROM Table2
            GROUP BY ObjectId
        ) T2
    ON T1.ObjectId = T2.ObjectId
GROUP BY T1.[Year]
```

I do see some potential problems with your data structure, e.g, there is no `Year` reference in `Table2`, however, if your data is under control, it should all work out.

Comment: There is no year column in second table. Anyways your solution works. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Same answer as mine, only one minute later. Sorry. +1 from me :-)

Comment: Thanks, gave you a +1 too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your datamodel allows for an object ID to appear in multiple years. The related table2 entries would thus be multiplied, i.e. added to every of these years. If you don't want this, then you need a separate table with one record per object.

As is you'd aggregate the first table by year and object ID and the second by object ID only. Then join and aggregate again to get years.

```
select
  t1.year,
  sum(t1.totalg) as total_g_amount,
  coalesce(sum(t2.totali), 0) as total_i_amount
from 
(
  select Year, ObjectId, sum(G_Amount) as totalg
  from table1 
  group by Year, ObjectId
) t1
left join
(
  select ObjectId, sum(i_Amount) as totali
  from table2
  group by ObjectId
) t2 on t2.ObjectId = t1.ObjectId
group by t1.year
order by t1.year;
```

Comment: Let me try all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , anyway i am new to T-SQL so it can be wrong .

```
Select DISTINCT T1.Year 
       SUM (T1.G_Amount) as G_Amount,
       SUM (T2.I_Amount) AS I_Amount
from table1 T1 join Table2 T2 on T1.ObjectID = T2.ObjectID
```

Comment: Unfortunately this *is* wrong. With two rows for object 1234 in each table, your join produces 2 x 2 = 4 rows for it, thus multiplicating the amounts.